# How to retrieve html code as preview among text in sql php

Tags: php, html, sql

I submitted some text to an SQL database like this:

*"You can check my photo below (img src=..myimg.jpg..)and please also comment."*

Now i want to retrieve it in PHP and containing image preview. The image code is HTML.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take few moments to take a [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)  to get better answers for your questions

Answer (score 1):

You need to [escape data](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) from DB before presenting it in page in order to what is stored doesn't mess with your page. But if you want also show the image, then you have to extract the img src part and put it back inside escaped output in proper html tag.